# how to prevent calling onbeforeunload when page refresh in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want application should be logged out whenever I visit any new site in the same tab which has already login whenever I click back button it should go to the login page for that I am using I am using javascript window.on-before unload but whenever I am refreshing the page its log out 
so I need any other solution in angular js or java script

Comment: are you using `angular-ui-router`?

Comment: There is no way to differentiate between page refresh and leaving the page in `onbeforeunload` unless a link is clicked inside your app to go to another site.

Comment: angular-ui-router is not used in application